# Outputting pandas timestamp to tuple with just month and day

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe with a timestamp field which I have successfully to converted to datetime format and now I want to output just the month and day as a tuple for the first date value in the data frame. It is for a test and the output must not have leading zeros. I ahve tried a number of things but I cannot find an answer without converting the timestamp to a string which does not work.
This is the format
2021-05-04 14:20:00.426577

`df_cleaned['trans_timestamp']=pd.to_datetime(df_cleaned['trans_timestamp'])` is as far as I have got with the code.

I have been working on this for days and cannot get output the checker will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

If you want to extract month and day from the first record (*solution proposed by @FObersteiner*)

```
>>> df['trans_timestamp'].iloc[0].timetuple()[1:3]
(5, 4)
```

If you want extract all month and day from your dataframe, use:

```
# Setup
df = pd.DataFrame({'trans_timestamp': ['2021-05-04 14:20:00.426577']})
df['trans_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['trans_timestamp'])

# Extract tuple
df['month_day'] = df['trans_timestamp'].apply(lambda x: (x.month, x.day))
print(df)

# Output
             trans_timestamp month_day
0 2021-05-04 14:20:00.426577    (5, 4)
```

Comment: q reads as if OP just wants `df['trans_timestamp'].iloc[0].timetuple()[1:3]`?

Comment: It was not clear for me what OP wants. I updated my solution based on your comment. I give you the credits of this answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help I have adjusted the code to find the first date in the dataframe but the checker is still not accepting the output. Is there any way to have the leading zeros in the output but it may not be that.

Comment: thanks for all you help everyone

Comment: The code works fine thanks all for your help